# Pub/Sub push message not having messageId property

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

This may deserve an issue against the Cloud Pub/Sub service. But so far the GCP support isn't really helpful so I am posting this issue here.

According to [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage), the Pubsub message should have a messageId property, whether it's from pull or push.

So I am trying to see what the message looks like: (event here is the pubsub message pushed to the cloud function)

```
exports.my_cloud_function = (event) => {
    logger.debug(`Event: ${util.inspect(event)}`);
}
```

What I expected:

```
{ '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage', messageId:'111111111', publishTime: 'Oct 1st 2019, xxxx', attributes: { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, data: 'eLCJ=(some base 64)' }
```

What actually is:

```
{ '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage', attributes: { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, data: 'eLCJ=(some base 64)' }
```

Comment: Edit your question and show how this message is generated. You say that Google is not helpful. Post the Issue Tracker details with your question so that I can look this up.

Comment: How is your message being published to the topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I guess well, you are using a Cloud Function with an event trigger. And it's a common trap (I felt in it several times...).

So, in event format, the publishedTime and the messageId are in the `context` object and not in the event as describe [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#event_structure)

In your function, add the context in param, and print it. It should work.

```
exports.my_cloud_function = (event,context) => {
    logger.debug(`Event: ${util.inspect(event)}`);
    logger.debug(`Context: ${util.inspect(context)}`);
}
```

Comment: Found it. Thanks! 
`{ eventId: '774460954950556', timestamp: '2019-10-06T04:04:20.631Z', eventType: 'providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish', resource: 'projects/myProject' }`